# gnome-shell in Linux Fedora "fakes" exit

Tags: gnome-shell, gdm

My question is about the behaviour of `gnome-shell`, started on login through the GNOME display manager, in a Fedora 24 framework.

If I issue from the Linux console the command

```
ps -aux
```

(after logging out from the gnome-shell) I still see *all* my processes running, and the only way to stop them is to send a `kill` interrupt.

Does anyone know why pressing the "End session" button on the upper right
menu makes you exit from the session without stopping any associated process?

Comment: This is a known behavior, and the reason for a controversial change (`KillUserProcesses=yes`) in `systemd`

Comment: @Fox - do you have a link to the support your answer or for more information?

Comment: @Tigger I should have added links before.  From a quick search, there are bug reports to [DBus](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94508) (which systemd implements) and [GNOME](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=764146).  Here is the [changelog](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v230/NEWS) from the systemd release that introduced `KillUserProcesses`

Comment: @Tigger See also this [feature request](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/428#issuecomment-222330478) to `tmux`, a request for `tmux` to change in order to accommodate systemd's new default behavior